# Finding critical points of $-2 x^3+33 x^2-180 x+1$ This function has two critical points.

Tags: calculus

The first move here is to set this equal to zero as I understand it. This gives me x = approx 0.0055612. Problem says there should be two. Very early roadblock here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=-2x^3+33x^2-180x+1$

Critical points are when the derivative equals 0.

$y'=-6x^2+66x-180$. Let $y'=0 \implies -6x^2+66x-180=0$. Solve this quadratic, and then substitute these x-values into $y$ to find the y-ordinate of the critical point.

Comment: Minor quibble, critical points are when the derivative is 0 or undefined.  (Example:  $|x|$ has a critical point at 0)

Comment: Ahh. Understood.